# Solving a typical calculus question without using calculus.

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Alright the question is this:

> Find all values of $f(x)$ in range $<-1;3>$; $f(x) = 4^x - 2^{x+1} - 8$.

Now usually when approaching these types of questions I would just take the derivative and look for local minimums/maximums and calculate values at the range boundaries, but we haven't been taught the derivative for exponentials in school yet, so I wasn't able to answer this on a test.

At home I was able to find the derivative and the question becomes TRIVIALLY easy, but without it I am simply stuck. Is there a way to reasonably approach this without derivatives or some guessing and checking?

Comment: You can use $a=2^x$.

Comment: Say, $x^2-2x+1$ is **not** something you need a derivative to find the minimum of. Now, your case is just two steps away from this...

Answer (score 4):

$$4^x-2^{x+1}-8=2^{2x}-2\cdot 2^{x}-8=(2^x-1)^2-9$$

Now, $-1 \le x\le 3$, then we have $\frac12 \le 2^x \le 8$ hence we have

$$-\frac12 \le 2^x-1\le 7$$

Now try to take square, be careful not to just take square both sides. The lower-bound should be $0$ at this stage.

After that, subtract by $9$.